# How to use bit-wise operators using methods in java?

Tags: java, methods

I have this homework assignment where I have to use bit wise operators with methods. I need to use methods for each of the operators. The interface BitOperators are givens that I need to use. I was able to do this without using methods but it is required for me to use methods. Here is what I have but it's not working. I am fairly new to methods so I am not sure what to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestBitOperators {

public static interface BitOperators {
  BitOperators and(byte a, byte b);
  BitOperators or(byte a, byte b);
  BitOperators xor(byte a, byte b);
  BitOperators shift(byte n, byte l, byte r);
  BitOperators comp(byte n);
}
static int and;
static int or;
static int xor;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte a;
    byte b;
    byte l;
    byte r;
    final byte EXIT = -1;

    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
    System.out.println("Enter a and b numbers in the "
            + "interval [-128,127] (-1 -1 to exit): ");

    a = stdin.nextByte();
    b = stdin.nextByte();

    }
    if(a == EXIT && b == EXIT){
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("Enter #left-shift bits in the interval [0,8]: ");
    l = stdin.nextByte();

    System.out.println("Enter #right-shift bits in the interval [0,8]: ");
    r = stdin.nextByte();

    }

    System.out.println(a + " OR " + b + " is " + and);
    System.out.println(a + " OR " + b + " is " + or);
    System.out.println(a + " XOR " + b + " is " + xor);
    System.out.println(a + " shifted left " + a + " is " + (a << l));
    System.out.println(a + " shifted right " + a + " is " + (a >> r));
    System.out.println(a + " unsigned-shifted right " + a + 
            " is " + (a >>> r));
    System.out.println(a + " COMPLEMENT " + (~a));
    }
    while((a < abMAX && b < abMAX) && (a > abMIN && b > abMIN));
}
public static int and(byte a, byte b){
    and = a&b;
   return and;
}
public static int or(byte a, byte b){
    or = a|b;
    return or;
}
public static int xor(byte a, byte b){
    xor = a^b;
    return xor;
}
}
```

Comment: You never seem to call your methods.You may do things like  `System.out.println(a + " OR " + b + " is " + or(a,b));`

Comment: In your methods you are referring to static variables. This should be changed to local variables, or eliminate the variables completely.  For `and`, you should do only `return a&b;`. Same for the others, no need to store the result in a temporary.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote right methods for performing bitwise operator, but seems you are not using them:

You should call methods you have created rather than accessing static variables:

```
System.out.println(a + " AND " + b + " is " + and(a, b));
System.out.println(a + " OR " + b + " is " + or(a, b));
System.out.println(a + " XOR " + b + " is " + xor(a, b));
```

Useful link: [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)